# Regex to capture the group

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text where I want to capture email with line starting from "Email: ******"

```
Details of Contact Made: 
Sender's Name: Test (Individual) 
Mobile: 4354354354 
Email: 7c92e312-93d5-4354354-45435435@email.webhook.site 
Message: I am interested in your property. Please get in touch with me 
Click here 
<https://www.magicbricks.com/bricks/mailerautologin.html?
```

I have tried with `.match(/Email\:(.*)\1/g)`

But I am getting `[Email:]` instead of `7c92e312-93d5-4354354-45435435@email.webhook.site`
How do I get the matching email from the group

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to access the first capture group.  But I would use this version:

```js
var text = `Details of Contact Made: 
Sender's Name: Test (Individual) 
Mobile: 4354354354 
Email: 7c92e312-93d5-4354354-45435435@email.webhook.site 
Message: I am interested in your property. Please get in touch with me 
Click here 
<https://www.magicbricks.com/bricks/mailerautologin.html?`;

var email = text.match(/Email:\s*(\S+?@\S+)/)[1];
console.log(email);
```

Answer (score 2):

This regex will get exactly what you want:

```
/(?<=Email: )(.*)/g
```

Please check https://regexr.com/6tuln

Answer (score 1):

The `\1` part in the pattern should not be there, as it is a backreference to what is captured in group 1.

You get `Email:` as a result because an empty string it the only possibility to capture and refer to the same captured value with `\1`

You also don't have to escape the colon.

---

Possible fixes with a capture group are:

```
Email:(.*)
Email:\s*(.+)
Email:\s*(\S+)
```

Or the more specific ones:

```
Email:\s*([^\s@]+@[^\s@]+)
\bEmail:\s*([^\s@]+@[^\s@]+)(?!\S)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z11a9j/1).